# How to set selected option in dropdown from session variable in laravel blade?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, laravel

I am using laravel framework in PHP.
In a view I have a project dropdown where user can select a particular project and the project is remain selected untill he doesn't change the project againg by selecting the dropdown.

I did this by having a session 'project', whenever user chnages the dropdown option the session is set to the value of selected project. I have done this but my issue is that i want to show the selected project name in the projects dropdown.
For this I think javascript will be a good solution , I have the following code-

```
$("#projectlist").find( option[value="{{Session::get('project')}}"]).attr("selected", "true");
```

where 'projectlist' is the id of dropdown and i want to set the selected option equal to the value stored in the session 'project'.
But I am not getting the selected option as per the session value.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using blade to achieve this, javascript is not what you'd want to use. For the project dropdown, just use the laravel `Form` library and provide it there.

```
{{ Form::select('projects', $projectList, Session::get('project')) }}
```

This way, it'll select whatever the value is, and you'll see that as the name. There's absolutely no need what so ever to use javascript, unless you're loading the currently selected project value in via ajax.

Answer (score -1):

You will want to use `val()` for this to set the value.  This is also assuming your javascript is being placed inside a `*.blade.php` file.

```
$("#projectlist").val({{Session::get('project')}});
```